React Mantine custom components
I'm still studying React, so I do not know how things work.
I want to use the Mantine component library, especially the Carousel component.
But I want to change its slider to a pager because I want to display data on it, not images.
Can it be used by page by default, or can I change its source according to my needs, please?
